# How to create a for loop in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, loops

I'm looking for a way to iterate some process in order to write less in math mode.
Let's take an example.

```
\[
  F_x = q\left[\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x}\operatorname{d}x + 
  \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial y}\operatorname{d}y + 
  \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial x}\operatorname{d}z\right]
\]
```

produces the output
[image]
Now what I would like were to automatise the iteration of writing with something loop-like, as below:

```
\[
  F_x = q\left[for \i in {x, y, z} +\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial \i}\operatorname{d}\i  
  \right]
\]
```

something similar to the for loop in `TikZ` to avoid repetition in writing. 
is it someway possible?

Comment: Do you think your code would be easy to read, in case of a compilation problem?

Comment: `\usepackage{pgffor}` and then `\foreach \i in {x,y,z} {+\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial\i} \dd \i` (with `\newcommand*\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`. But you get an extra `+`. To take care of the `+` you could do `\if x\i\else+\fi` instead of `+`, but think about code readability.

Comment: @Bernard my code is almost 2000 lines, so I prefer to shorten what I can, even giving up some readability, as a so long code it's not readable though.

Comment: @Manuel could you provide a more clear example, I cannot understand how to deal with those pieces of code, thanks! 
P.S: I don't care about the +, as long as I can compress lines `:-)`

Comment: You might be able to shorten more by defining macros with repeated expressions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\[
F_x = q\left[\foreach \i/\p in {x/, y/+, z/+} {\p\frac{\partial E_\i}{\partial \i}\mathrm{d}\i}  
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Note: loading tikz is overkill.

Comment: Note the last differentiated function is not $E_x$, but $E_z$…

Comment: I guess it makes the programming less simple…

Comment: I suspect that there is a typo in the original question.  But I'll leave it as is, now.  Refinements should be clear to the OP.

Comment: You're probably right.

Comment: @JPi thanks, no typo in the source , is the $x$ component of the electric field everywhere as i'm looking for the $x$ component of the force filed. This solution seems to be the best, as I already load `TikZ` package for other reasons `:-)`

Comment: BTW great solution, @JPi, even with the conditional plus so that there's no + for the first term!

Comment: You can just load `pgffor` to get access to the loop without loading all of TikZ.

Comment: so.. what did you do?

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\z[2]{\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial #1}\operatorname{d}#1
             \ifx\z#2+\fi#2}
\begin{document}

\[
  F_x = q\left[\z x\z y\z z\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure it’s worth the trouble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\totaldiff}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_opisthofulax_variables_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_opisthofulax_variables_seq \l_opisthofulax_firstvar_tl
  \frac{\partial #1}{\partial\l_opisthofulax_firstvar_tl}\diff\l_opisthofulax_firstvar_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_opisthofulax_variables_seq
   {
    +\frac{\partial #1}{\partial##1}\diff ##1
   }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_opisthofulax_variables_seq
\tl_new:N \l_opisthofulax_firstvar_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
F_x=q\biggl[\totaldiff{E}{x,y,z}\biggr]
\]

\[
\totaldiff{f}{x}\qquad \totaldiff{g}{u,v}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\operatorname{d}x` gives wrong spacing.

A more general version, where a `\doloop` macro is defined, taking as arguments a comma separated list of items and a template for doing the job. There's also an optional trailing argument for setting the separator between successive applications of the cycle.

Some examples of usage are given.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\doloop}{mmO{+}}
 {% #1 = variables for the loop, #2 = template, #3 = separator, default +
  \giutex_doloop:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\clist_new:N \l__giutex_doloop_clist
\tl_new:N \l__giutex_doloop_tl

% initialize
\cs_new:Nn \__giutex_doloop_first:n {}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__giutex_doloop_first:n { V }
\cs_new:Nn \__giutex_doloop:n {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \giutex_doloop:nnn
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__giutex_doloop_first:n { #2 }
  \cs_set:Nn \__giutex_doloop:n { #3 #2 }
  \clist_set:Nn \l__giutex_doloop_clist { #1 }
  \clist_pop:NN \l__giutex_doloop_clist \l__giutex_doloop_tl
  \__giutex_doloop_first:V \l__giutex_doloop_tl
  \clist_map_function:NN \l__giutex_doloop_clist \__giutex_doloop:n
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% if you define a command in terms of \doloop, the variable item is denoted by ##1
\newcommand{\totaldiff}[2]{%
  \doloop{#2}{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial##1}\diff##1}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
F_x=q\Bigl[\doloop{x,y,z}{\frac{\partial E}{\partial#1}\diff#1}\Bigr]
\]

\[
F_x=q\Bigl[\totaldiff{E}{x,y,z}\Bigr]
\]

\[
D(f+g+h)=\doloop{f,g,h}{\frac{\diff #1}{\diff x}}
\]

\[
n!=\doloop{n,(n-1),\dotsb,3,2,1}{#1}[\cdot]
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that the current item in the loop is denoted by `#1`; this has to be `##1` if `\doloop` is used to define another macro such as `\totaldiff`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why that `\mathop{}\!` before the `\mathrm`?

Comment: @opisthofulax In order to get the desired thin space in front of the ‘d’.

Comment: Nice! Anyway you're right by saying "Not sure it’s worth the trouble", I was looking for something to shorten my code... `:-)`

Comment: @opisthofulax The document code is dramatically shorter, actually.

Comment: Yes, of course, but it's very specific to the case I have partial derivatives, while I was looking more for something general (the derivatives one was only an example, but I need this for a bunch of other things), more like the the answer of JPi.

Comment: @opisthofulax That's code obfuscation. A macro `\pder` such as `\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}` would be much more useful.

Comment: Yes, I already have that command, but I can't define a newcommand every time I have to shorten up the code, also if you have something like 10-20 derivatives a for results much more fast then writing 10 times `\pderiv{}{}`. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Obviously I won't use the tikz command every 2 lines, but it's much more simple to understand and to write.

Answer (score 6):

If you use a macro for the differential symbol and the `esdiff` package, you can have a shorter code and a better spacing. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\mkern-2mu{}}

\begin{document}
\[
  F_x = q\left[\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x}\operatorname{d}x +
  \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial y}\operatorname{d}y +
  \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial x}\operatorname{d}z\right]
\]

\[ F_x = q\left[\diffp{E_x}{x}\dd x + \diffp{E_x}{y}\dd y + \diffp{E_z}{x}\dd z \right] \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\mkern-2mu`? when `\!` is precisely the space added by `\mathop`? (Which is 3mu IIRC)

Comment: I prefer a very thin distance between the differential operator and the variable, but that's my personal taste.

Comment: I prefer without space too... as a matter of facts in my code I don't use `\operatorname`. Thanks anyway.